# Laravel Mail::send 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm getting a 500 internal server error when trying to use `Mail::send()`. Frustratingly this has only just started happening, it was working fine before. The really frustrating part about this is I'm just getting the white screen of death. I've turned on debugging in config/app.php and set the environment to LOCAL, but I get nothing.

I've checked cPanel errors but there's nothing in them, it's not generating an error at all. Error reporting is definitely on, I added a call to an undefined function at the top of index.php and it showed me `Fatal error: Call to undefined function throw_error_now() in /home/fluidstu/tracker/public_html/index.php on line 8` as expected, so that's not the issue.

How can I find out what is causing the issue if there's nothing in the logs (Laravel or cPanel) and I'm just getting a white screen of death when calling `Mail::send`?

I'd really appreciate some help on this as I'm about to throw my PC out the window.

Comment: Make sure to check your Apache/Nginx error log (not sure if these are in cPanel or not) and to make sure you have `postfix` or something similar installed on the server.

Comment: Did you have xdebug installed? If not then (1) use `pretend=true` to test your code without including smtp server in place. (2) use another email account. If you are pretty sure that credentials are ok (3) then make a script only to test email credentials.  (4) Make sure that laravel log's are writable

Comment: I don't have xdebug, where would you put `pretend=true`? I'm not using SMTP, I'm using the mail function. SMTP has an SSL issue. Laravels log's are writable, I've got other errors from hours before in them, unrelated. Thanks for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP request can be taking to long to process, you can try rise the time_limit, but it's highly unsafe.

```
set_time_out(0);
```

Comment: It's not a timeout, it happens in less than a second.

Comment: Yes, I actually put some in to see where it would fail. I put `die('test');` in to see where it failed. When it stopped showing `test` I knew it failed. It showed just before `Mail::send`, but didn't show if I put the `die` after `Mail::send`.